# Servlet Session

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have written  a small piece of code to understand session...here is the code

```
public class SessionServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws    IOException,ServletException
{
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
if(session.isNew())
{
out.println("Client has not responded");

}
else out.println("Client has responded");
}
}
```

With my understand while running i program for the first time it should "Client has not responded" however its its printing the first statement...can one explain why its doing that.

Comment: *Client has not responded* **is** the first statement. Did you mean... second?

Comment: yes when i am running it for first time its saying---"client has responded".....where i am doing wrong

Comment: Your code looks fine then. Are you using JSP by any chance? Are you restarting your browser to make sure cookies are gone? Can you examine HTTP request/response headers and look for `JSESSIONID`?

Comment: how to do that can you help me in this...?

Comment: Hi there i was using chrome which were already ahaving some tab opens...now i changed it to IE and it works fine....can it be related

Comment: also can anyone help me in session management as iam struggling in it a lot

Comment: @user728907 For instance, check out "Session Tracking" lesson on this page: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK, to test it make sure that you **clear your browser cache/cookies** to make sure that old session is removed.

Answer (score 0):

If its JSP your accessing before the request reaches the servlet , you should probably check for a setting

`<%@ page session="true" %>`

in JSP.

Change it to **<%@ page session="false" %>** , because having it true , means JSP will participate in a session and no session found it will create one , even before the request reaches the servlet